# Using vtk.js as an ES6 dependency

Tags: javascript, vtk.js

I have followed a tutorial (https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/intro_vtk_as_es6_dependency.html#Webpack-config) to build an application vtk.js and I have created the project structure and the different packages. When I want to build the application with the command : 'npm run build' I have an error message that says 'Unexpected identifier'.